# App Script HTML form connection issue with firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-apps-script

I'm currently working on a project where I have a mobile app that droplist gets its data from firebase.
In order to modify the droplist remotely, I thought of connecting the current firebase to an html form in app script.

The form is displayed but the data not and no connection established.

Here an example of the code:

HTML file (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Firebase CRUD Form</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Firebase CRUD Form</h1>

    <form id="fruitForm">
        <label for="fruit">Select a fruit:</label>
        <select id="fruit" name="fruit"></select>

        <br><br>

        <label for="newFruit">Add a new fruit:</label>
        <input type="text" id="newFruit" name="newFruit">

        <button type="button" onclick="addFruit()">Add</button>

        <br><br>

        <label>Edit fruit:</label>
        <input type="text" id="editFruit" name="editFruit">
        <button type="button" onclick="editFruit()">Edit</button>

        <br><br>

        <label>Delete fruits:</label>
        <ul id="fruitList"></ul>

        <button type="button" onclick="deleteFruits()">Delete</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            authDomain: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            databaseURL: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            projectId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            storageBucket: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            messagingSenderId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            measurementId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // Get the reference to the Firebase database
        var database = firebase.database();

        // Function to dynamically populate the dropdown list with fruits
        function populateFruits() {
            var fruitSelect = document.getElementById("fruit");
            fruitSelect.innerHTML = "";

            database.ref('fruits').once('value', function(snapshot) {
                snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                    var fruit = childSnapshot.val();
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = fruit;
                    option.text = fruit;
                    fruitSelect.appendChild(option);
                });
            });
        }

        // Populate the fruit dropdown list on page load
        populateFruits();

        function addFruit() {
            var newFruit = document.getElementById("newFruit").value;

            if (newFruit !== "") {
                document.getElementById("newFruit").value = ""; // Clear the input field

                // Save the new fruit to Firebase
                database.ref('fruits').push(newFruit);
                // Repopulate the fruit dropdown list
                populateFruits();
            }
        }

        function editFruit() {
            var selectedFruit = document.getElementById("fruit").value;
            var editedFruit = document.getElementById("editFruit").value;

            if (selectedFruit !== "" && editedFruit !== "") {
                // Update the fruit in Firebase
                database.ref('fruits').orderByValue().equalTo(selectedFruit).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                    snapshot.ref.set(editedFruit);
                    // Repopulate the fruit dropdown list
                    populateFruits();
                });
            }
        }

        function deleteFruits() {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("fruitsToDelete");
            var fruitsToDelete = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
                    fruitsToDelete.push(checkboxes[i].value);
                }
            }

            if (fruitsToDelete.length > 0) {
                // Delete selected fruits from Firebase
                fruitsToDelete.forEach(function(fruit) {
                    database.ref('fruits').orderByValue().equalTo(fruit).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                        snapshot.ref.remove();
                        // Repopulate the fruit dropdown list
                        populateFruits();
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Google Apps Script file (Code.gs)

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function include(filename) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

HTML file (script.html)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Here is the link of the form :

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzxhR39CMwUqmxacMbU6Jt47Wy_HbyrRH25SFaUn0vFL8I583K4CnSybSOgG3f5elSOyA/exec

Also, while inspecting the console, I found the following errors:

[image]

Grateful if you could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused between [the namespaced API and the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#modular-version).

> **JavaScript - namespaced**. This is the JavaScript interface that Firebase maintained for many years and is familiar to Web developers with older Firebase apps. Because the namespaced API does not benefit from ongoing new feature support, most new apps should instead adopt the modular API.

> **JavaScript - modular**. This SDK is based on a modular approach that provides reduced SDK size and greater efficiency with modern JavaScript build tools such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/).

To summarize, both are 2 ways to use Web + Firebase but the namespaced API is an old one, and it doesn't receive updates anymore, while the modular API is the new one, and it's the recommended one to use.

Version 8 and lower is the namespaced API. Version 9 and higher is the modular API. Of course, both ways have different coding styles.

So currently you're importing the modular API (version 9 and higher) while using the coding style of the old namespaced API which is wrong and results in `firebase isn't defined`.

So now you should study the new modular API at [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start). Luckily Firebase documentation already differentiates between both APIs nicely:

[image: firebase documentation already differentiates between both APIs nicely]

*The highlighted "pink" one is the one you should use.*

Also, Firebase always notes about it: *Learn more about the tree-shakeable modular Web API and upgrade from the namespaced API.*

Also, I recommend reading the [Upgrade from the namespaced API to the modular API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) guide to know the difference between both.

Another solution would be importing the old namespace API to match the namespace coding style (the one you're currently using), which in this case, according to [Firebase JavaScript SDK Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_8100_-_august_19_2021), the latest version of the namespace API is `8.10.0`, so adjust your URL accordingly:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

But as I said, it's not recommended to use the old namespaced API anymore as it doesn't receive updates anymore, which is a great security issue.

Comment: @P.J You're welcome. Always ready to help :-)